# How to execute this brew installed tool 'gigtools'

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash

My goal is to to run this 'gigtools' folder which extracts and converts .gig [audio] files into .wav files.

Website: https://command-not-found.com/gigextract

So I've installed the commands with Xcode- and the 'instructions' say this :

```
SYNOPSIS

    gigextract [ -v ] GIGFILE DESTDIR [SAMPLENR] [ [SAMPLENR] ... ]
```

I'm not good at basic level coding by any means, but I would love an example string to type into terminal to properly execute this, assuming my .gig files are in my /Downloads folder for reference.

Comment: What do you mean by instructions? That text looks like the source code for a man page

Comment: This is the syntax of the command : 
 gigextract [ -v ] GIGFILE DESTDIR [SAMPLENR] [ [SAMPLENR] ... ]

Comment: Like I said, I'm absolutely novice at running these commands- I've learned I can just use "gigextract" followed by the location of the .gig to run the conversion to .wav. That worked great- however my new hurdle is being able to batch convert these. Have tried dragging multiple .gig files into the string, followed by the destination and it hits me with the error : Unable to open DESTDIR: Is not a directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
gigextract [-v] GIGFILE DESTDIR [SAMPLENR] [ [SAMPLENR] ...]
```

The following would extract the files in Downloads folder.

```
gigextract "~/Downloads/myfile.gig" "~/Downloads/"
```

Optionally add indices of samples you get from

```
gigdump "~/Downloads/myfile.gig"
```

A bit more help is at `gigextract --help`

---

For multiple files, you can use shell loops like

```
cd ~/Downloads
for g in *.gig; do gigextract "$g" ./; done
```

or, if you downloaded a whole directory structure of .gig files,

```
cd ~/Downloads
find . -name '*.gig' -execdir gigextract '{}' ./ \;
```

A less elegant way is to create a shell script like `extract.sh` which contains

```
cd ~/Downloads
gigextract "myfile.gig" ./
gigextract "myfile2.gig" ./
```

and run it with `sh extract.sh`

Comment: The second string worked ! This was only one file unfortunately- and I have close to a hundred I need to extract.


How would I run multiple ?

Comment: @john44v see the updated answer

Comment: For running a whole directory (I have a folder of .gig files divided into sub folders based on their content), where do I input the location of the folder I’m looking to extract? I see the destination is set to Downloads-

Comment: @john44v `-execdir` takes care of that. It'll switch to the folder where the file is stored and `./` will use that directory. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476126/how-does-find-execdir-command-work

Comment: This worked perfectly. It also allowed me to extract the .wavs into their respective sub folders. Much appreciated !